# Xcode 6 build project for iPhone 6 caused about 200 issues

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I just downloaded new Xcode and try to build my application using it. On the Xcode 5 everything goes ok, but when I try to build and run app, it caused about 200 errors here is a [log](http://codepaste.net/2e1ued)

Comment: first of all try to clean project, Window->Organizer-> Projects -> your project delete Derived data

Comment: thank you! I am not a new in iOS, of course I did it as a first suggestion =)